# What is the difference between geodetic datums and geodetic control networks?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have read that the geodetic horizontal datum is a modified ellipsoid in such local area then the control network is established starting from an origin, but in North America the horizontal control network and NAD83 are same, also the vertical control network in North America and NAVD88 are same